# How to turn text stored in a variable to a BeautifulSoup Object in Pyhton

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, rss

```
   for i in range(self.length):
        print(colored('Title', 'green', attrs=['bold']))
        print(self.url.entries[i].title)
        print(colored('Link', 'green', attrs=['bold']))
        print(self.url.entries[i].link)
        print(colored('Description', 'green', attrs=['bold']))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.url.entries[i].summary, 'html.parser')
        for s in soup.find_all('p'):
            print(s)
```

In this code I need to turn all the text stored in self.url.entries[i].summary to a BeautifulSoup object for each description section in the RSS Feed to print just the sections in the

tags. But, I cant find a way to do so.

The text stored in one of the self.url.entries[i].summary is:

```
    <img alt="APTOPIX Haiti Earthquake" src="https://i.cbc.ca/1.6143421.1629203330!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_460/aptopix-haiti-earthquake.jpg" title="People affected by the Saturday" width="460" />                <p>Heavy rain from Tropical Storm Grace forced a temporary halt to the government's response to the deadly earthquake that battered the impoverished Caribbean nation on Saturday. </p>
```

Comment: before doing the soup try to str()... it is not clear what kind of data you passed to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_text = ''' <img alt="APTOPIX Haiti Earthquake" src="https://i.cbc.ca/1.6143421.1629203330!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_460/aptopix-haiti-earthquake.jpg" title="People affected by the Saturday" width="460" />                <p>Heavy rain from Tropical Storm Grace forced a temporary halt to the government's response to the deadly earthquake that battered the impoverished Caribbean nation on Saturday. </p>'''

# Creates a beautifulsoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_text, 'lxml')
```